# c read() with pipe stays idle

Tags: c, stdout, pipe, stdin

I wrote this piece of code that is supposed to redirect something written on the STDOUT by a function to the STDIN so that it can be read by another function. I cannot access these functions, so this is the only way I can use them. 
`mpz_fput(stdout, c)` is one of these function. It just prints on the STDOUT something contained in the c data structure.

Now everything worked fine while debugging as before the following code I had a `printf();` followed by a `fflush(stdout);` (needed to print debugging messages). 
Now that I removed these two lines I noticed (using gdb) that this code stays idle on the `read()` function (last line of this piece of code)

```
char buffer[BUFSIZ] = "";
int out_pipe[2];
int in_pipe[2];
int saved_stdout;
int saved_stdin;
int errno;

// REDIRECT STDIN
saved_stdin = dup(STDIN_FILENO);    /* save stdin for later */
if(errno= pipe(in_pipe) != 0 ) {          /* make a pipe */
  printf("\n%s",strerror(errno));
  exit(1);
}
close(STDIN_FILENO);
dup2(in_pipe[0], STDIN_FILENO);     /* redirect pipe to stdin */

// REDIRECT STDOUT
saved_stdout = dup(STDOUT_FILENO);  /* save stdout for display later */
if(errno= pipe(out_pipe) != 0 ) {          /* make a pipe */
  printf("\n%s",strerror(errno));
  exit(1);
}
dup2(out_pipe[1], STDOUT_FILENO);   /* redirect stdout to the pipe */
close(out_pipe[1]);

mpz_fput(stdout,c);         // put c on stdout
read(out_pipe[0], buffer, BUFSIZ);  // read c from stdout pipe into buffer
```

any idea why is that?

Comment: How do you call your program ? From where do you think your `read()` will read its data?

Comment: what is 'c' in the `mpz_fput` line? Does it have a \n to flush it?

Comment: @Eregrith I should have said this is only part of the code, I just posted the "interesting bit" as it gets stuck on the last line.

these are the two following lines where I put the contents of 'c' in the STDIN for the external program:

    write(in_pipe[1], buffer, strlen(buffer)); //write c to stdin pipe from buffer
      system("ep1617/time/ep1617.oracle"); // invoke oracle

Comment: @WilliamMorris yes, last thing mpz_fput() puts on stdout is a \n character

Comment: By the way, the error handling isn't quite right.  pipe() doesn't return the errno.

Comment: I managed to make it work simply adding a `fflush(stdout);` before the `read()`.
But I wouldn't know the reason why it works now. Hope it's gonna help someone else :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you used the blocking type. In this case, out_pipe[0] is a blocking handle. So read() blocked, and waiting for anything out from out_pipe[0].

Besides, I think there's something to do with the fflush():

> For output streams, fflush() forces a write of all user-space buffered data
>          for the given output or update stream via the stream's underlying write
>          function.  For input streams, fflush() discards any buffered data that has
>          been fetched from the underlying file, but has not been by the application.
>          The open status of the stream is unaffected.

In your case, you redirected pipe to STDOUT, then called fflush() to make everything in STDOUT flushed and move them to read() buffer. Then you called read() to read them out. If you didn't call fflush(), and read() buffer would be empty. Since it's a blocking handle used by read(), you can't read anything from the buffer, so it will be blocked.

This is the brief theory, I suggest you to read Linux manpage for more details.

Comment: What I don't get is why it works perfectly if I put a printf(); followed by a fflush(stdout); on top of it